# Is it possible to write rules using template string variables in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to write a rule that would do the following:

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.players.$(request.auth.uid).id;
```

The goal is to check a dynamic field that depends on what the uid is.

The `$(something)` templating syntax works in [document paths](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions#access_other_documents) but doesn't work for actual document properties.

Is there any way to do this with the Firestore rules?

Answer (score 0):

Sure can, and you were very close. This is a rule I have to only allow moderators or admins to update:

```
allow update: if request.auth.uid in request.resource.data.moderators || get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin == true
```

Key piece for you is:

```
$(request.auth.uid)
```

Comment: This only works when your parameter is in the path of the document though. In my case, I want to check the existence of a specific field, and the field is supposed to be the value of `request.auth.uid`. It's not a document id, it's a value inside a document

Comment: That's what the second part does. This checks the "admin" field inside a document, where the path to get there was dynamic: `get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.admin`